# Syntax question for assigning an existing user to a login account in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, permissions, user-accounts

If I was creating a brand new login credentials in a brand new Azure database,
I would do the following:

```
create login kmistry with Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
Create User AuditUser from login kmistry
```

Now that I already have AuditUser defined with all necessary permissions, I want to create another similar login.

```
create login jperez with Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Now, I don't want to create AuditUser.
I just want to say jperez is also an AuditUser.

How do I do that assignment?

Comment: You can't map multiple SQL Users to a single SQL Login. What you are asking can't be done. If you want them to have the same permissions, then this is why Roles exist. A `LOGIN` must have a mapped `USER` in the database to use it (with the exception of `sysadmin` Logins, which inherit `dbo` and even then, can still do **anything**).

Comment: thanks.  i was going crazy lookin for a way.  i wonder why they made 2 concepts like that... login and user....   so if it is 1-1 then i will just create login kmistry and user kmistry, and do the same for all my users....

Comment: i guess its like that because login belongs to the whole server whereas user is database-specific....

Comment: A `LOGIN` and `USER` are different object types. A `LOGIN` is an Server level objects, bit a `USER` is a database level one. One can exist without the other, but that can be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Larnu said, One login for one user. We can not map multiple SQL users to one login.

`LOGIN` is SQL Server level and User is database level. That's why [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) must be in master db, and [CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) only need to be in the current database.

`LOGIN` is used to login the SQL Server, you need to grant the `USER` different roles to determine which database the user has the permission to access or alter. Ref: [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

In usually, we often create the login and user with the same name.

Hope this helps.